# The Message couldn't be delivered 250.2.6.0

Tags: email, exchange-2010, queue

Hello I have a Exchange 2010 server and I am having issues with 1 Domain trying to send us emails. I have the Anti Spam rule on and have whitelisted their email address and domain and even their IP of their SMTP server and I still get

Failed
2/27/2017 2:05 PM Exchange Server name here
The message couldn't be delivered.

250 2.6.0 <98b9b92f1f784f2bfc09ab169bd52f20@support.officeally.com> Queued mail for delivery

[screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LvMHS.png)